# Delay a snippet of code

Tags: ajax, delay

```
var ajaxRequestqqq;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
  // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
  ajaxRequestqqq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch (e){
  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
   ajaxRequestqqq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
   try{
    ajaxRequestqqq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e){
    // Something went wrong
    alert("Your browser broke!");
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
 ajaxRequestqqq.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequestqqq.readyState == 4){

   var ajaxDisplayqqq = document.getElementById('rajax');
   ajaxDisplayqqq.innerHTML = ajaxRequestqqq.responseText;
  }
 }



 var rurlvar = $("#rurl").val();
 var rnameval = $("#rname").val();
 var queryStringqqq = "url=" + rurlvar + "&name=" + rnameval;
 var urltofileqqq = "subrssajax.php";
 ajaxRequestqqq.open("POST", urltofileqqq, true);
 ajaxRequestqqq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajaxRequestqqq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryStringqqq.length);
 ajaxRequestqqq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
 ajaxRequestqqq.send(queryStringqqq); 

         ***#DELAY#***


 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
  // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch (e){
  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
   ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
   try{
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e){
    // Something went wrong
    alert("Your browser broke!");
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

   var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('vrname');
   ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
  }
 }



 //var rurlvar = $("#rurl").val();
 //var rnameval = $("#rname").val();
 //var queryString = "url=" + rurlvar + "&name=" + rnameval;
 var queryString = "url=sss";
 var urltofile = "rname.php";
 ajaxRequest.open("POST", urltofile, true);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryString.length);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
 ajaxRequest.send(queryString);
```

How to set delay between the two requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setTimeout` and refactor your code, something like this:

```
function createRequest() {
    var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try {
            ajaxRequestqqq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequestqqq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return ajaxRequest;
}

function setResponse(request, elementId) {
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(elementId);
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

}

function request1() {

    var ajaxRequestqqq = createRequest(); // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    setResponse(ajaxRequestqqq, 'rajax');

    var rurlvar = $("#rurl").val();
    var rnameval = $("#rname").val();
    var queryStringqqq = "url=" + rurlvar + "&name=" + rnameval;
    var urltofileqqq = "subrssajax.php";
    ajaxRequestqqq.open("POST", urltofileqqq, true);
    ajaxRequestqqq.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequestqqq.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryStringqqq.length);
    ajaxRequestqqq.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    ajaxRequestqqq.send(queryStringqqq);

}

function request2() {
    var ajaxRequest = createRequest(); // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    setResponse(ajaxRequest, 'vrname');

    // var rurlvar = $("#rurl").val();
    // var rnameval = $("#rname").val();
    // var queryString = "url=" + rurlvar + "&name=" + rnameval;
    var queryString = "url=sss";
    var urltofile = "rname.php";
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", urltofile, true);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryString.length);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    ajaxRequest.send(queryString);

}

// Call first request
request1();
// Setup delay in milliseconds
var delay = 5000; // 5 seconds
setTimeout(request2(), delay);
```